# confluence, excel macro: spaces in imported excel file are breaking the cells in confluence created doc

Tags: excel, confluence

I have excel file, which I successfully imported to confluence, using Excel from macro browser (just to new blank doc in confluence).

But column width, in which cells values have spaces (like "Values Have Spaces")  is broken, and corresponding column looks bad (some rows instead of one in corresponding cells).

[image: broken column width]

Guessing: its due to the spaces. If change with smth like "no_spaces_now" - rows became ok in excel confluence file.

How to fix this without removing spaces? (Rows in original local Excel file are looking good).

Comment: My guess is that the column is too narrow to show all of the text on one line and that the cells are set for **Justified** (i.e. *fill complete line width*) alignment.

Comment: Jeeped, thanx a lot! Exactly, shrinking was "on" there... All seems so easy, when know how:). Gimme five, dude! I can't vote for answer in comment:(.

Comment: Let's chalk this up to a simple problem that cannot be reproduced. btw, the effort you put into your question was appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is partially fixed with proposed by Jeeped checking/setting the formats. Other problem (with absence of horisontal scrolling for excel on confluence, at least in this case) raised with Atlassian.

this question will be closed as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, myself.

Imported Excel seemed to justify any of my columns, so the spacing looked ugly, as in the OP's attached image.  I did not do any formatting to default excel columns (I try to avoid formatting or anything fancy in excel as importing to confluence always results in some sort of uglifying of excel)

Anyways, the fix for me was to Center (horizontal) my excel text (which obviously looks ugly in Excel).  Doing this meant my cell text in the imported table is now aligned left, rather than Justified.

If anyone has found a better solution, and can properly describe it, I would be delighted to hear.  :)